# Audits contain other tags when filtering close reviews

Tags: discussion, tags, review, review-audits

When you place a filter on the close review queue and a review audit is placed, the question will almost always be for a different language entirely (for example I filter for [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and I get a question about [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), with the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag tacked on - it isn't there on the real question). Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or not, and should this be changed?

Comment: Example audits?

Comment: @Emrakul: sorry if I didn't make it clear, it's not there on the real question

Comment: Cool, then I'd call this a feature request.